# Sending Message to Azure Service Bus works locally, but not from service deployed on AWS

Tags: azure, azureservicebus

The following code works to send the message to an `Azure Service Bus Queue` when I run my service locally. The service is written with JAVA and with the Spring Boot Framework. The service is deployed on AWS, but needs to access the queue on Azure.

```
      // create a Service Bus Sender client for the queue
      ServiceBusSenderClient senderClient = new ServiceBusClientBuilder()
          .connectionString("myPrimaryConnectionStringForSending")
          // .transportType(AmqpTransportType.AMQP_WEB_SOCKETS)
          .sender()
          .queueName("myQueueName")
          .buildClient();
      // send one message to the queue
      senderClient.sendMessage(new ServiceBusMessage("Hello World!"));
```

This is the error message i get from the deployed service:

```
Caused by: com.azure.core.amqp.exception.AmqpException: Connection refused, errorContext[NAMESPACE: my-env-services-servicebus-namespace.servicebus.windows.net. ERROR CONTEXT: N/A]
```

When I try to send it with the `.transportType(AmqpTransportType.AMQP_WEB_SOCKETS)` line then I receive following error:

```
c.a.c.a.i.ReactorConnection              : onConnectionError connectionId[MF_074e33_164373...], hostName[proxy.private.emea.vwapps.io], message[Starting new reactor], error[protocol = my-env-services-servicebus-namespace.servicebus.windows.net host = null, TrackingId: d0b2ba5d-f5d9-4104-b5fa-..., at: 2022-02-01T17:29:51.299629Z[Etc/UTC], errorContext[NAMESPACE: my-env-services-servicebus-namespace.servicebus.windows.net. ERROR CONTEXT: N/A]]
```

Comment: Are there Service Bus firewall rules? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/service-bus-messaging/service-bus-ip-filtering#:~:text=The%20IP%20firewall%20rules%20are%20applied%20at%20the,the%20Service%20Bus%20namespace%20is%20rejected%20as%20unauthorized.

Comment: When you use AMQP_WEB_SOCKETS the library tries to make a connection using port 443, so it could be a firewall issue as David suggests above.

Comment: Doesn't seem related to SB firewall rules as you would get a 403 error if that was the case, but rather something in the middle either a firewall or proxy appears to be rejecting the connection, you might want to grab a network capture in whatever device is in between.

Comment: Ok thank you, it then seems that ASB is allowing the requests (at least that's what I read from the doc from David's comment and I don't get a 403 error). So it should be on the AWS side.